# TraceIdentifier for user end views correlation with traced exceptions or events

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, trace

Is `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` considered sensitive data?

Can I show this code in error views without compromising data security?

I'd like to assign this property to my error model:

```
errorModel.RequestId = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
```

And show it in my error view:

```
@if (Model.RequestId != null)
{
    <p>@request_id</p>
}
```

This same code is traced in App Insights in the Exceptions and some of my Custom Events. It would be a easy way to correlate user issues with my telemetry.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to logs where more information about the request/requestee is being kept it should be fine. Furthermore the request_id will only be shown to the person that actually initiated the request (unless someone stands behind them and watch, but in that case not even passwords would be safe).